# Apply margins to a scaled canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

Im fixing a html game my friend send me and the game is locked to 1080px so I wrote a JS script that uses transform: scale(n, n); that scales the canvas to fit the screen. However when it does that the top part of the canvas is displayed offscreen and i can't figure out how to apply margins automaticly to make it stay on screen

```
function percentage(partialValue, totalValue) {
    return (100 * partialValue) / totalValue;
 } 
var widprtp = percentage(self.innerWidth, 1048);
var higprtp = percentage(self.innerHeight, 772);
var render = document.getElementById("canvas")
render.style.transform = `scale(${widprtp}%,${higprtp}%)`
```

Im still new to StacksOverflow so let me know if you need more information
Sorry I gave the varibles weird names lol

Comment: You may use `max-height` in CSS instead of `transform`.

Comment: You could use: ``margin: auto;`` in your CSS, i think .... @vee there is also needed  to use the ``max-width``.

Comment: You may use `render.style.transformOrigin = '0 0';` to fix to the top left https://jsfiddle.net/jkh54p8m/16/